# How to get JNI-style signature string for a field or method?

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am trying to inspect a Java class and automatically retrieve all of its methods and fields in a way that I can invoke them via JNI on Android. However, I can't figure out how to actually get the textual signature string programmatically; I know how to get it via `javap -s` from the command line but I would like to get it from within my program.

The closest I can find is using `clazz.getMethods()` to get the individual methods, and then `Method.toGenericString()` to get a human-readable string, but that string is formatted like the Java code signature (e.g. `public int someMethod(int foo, java.lang.String bar)`) when I really just want the JNI-style signature (e.g. `(ILjava/lang/String;)I`), as I will need that string to call `getMethodID()` from JNI and I already have a perfectly-good parser that parses those JNI signatures in the first place.

I could just manually maintain bindings for the classes I actually care about accessing from JNI, but I'd much rather just have everything handled as automatically as possible; less code is better, after all.

I did find ASM which provides helper methods for this, but it appears to be a bytecode generation framework and I am not sure if it will be compatible with Android.

Or, in other words, given the following class:

```
class SomeClass {
    String foo(int bar) { return "This is foo " + bar; }
}
```

I want to create a class called `ClassInspector` which can do something like:

```
ClassInspector ci = new ClassInspector(SomeClass.class);
int n = ci.getMethodCount(); // returns 1
String name = ci.getMethodName(0); // returns "foo"
String sig = ci.getMethodSignature(0); // returns "(I)Ljava/lang/string;"
```

Which is to say that I want to be able to get the output of `javap -s` from within Java, so that I can call Java methods from the native side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar need and found a solution by digging through `JavapTask.java` from the [source code](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/tree/3787ff8d1d8dbcaaebb9616c5bc543e2fe21a90c/src/jdk.jdeps/share/classes/com/sun/tools/javap) of the `javap` tool.

Here is a snippet that does what you want:

```java
public class Test {
    String foo(int bar) { return "This is foo " + bar; }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class<?> c = Test.class;
        java.lang.reflect.Method methods[] = c.getDeclaredMethods();
        System.out.println("Class : " + c.getName());
        System.out.println("Number of methods : " + methods.length);
        for (java.lang.reflect.Method m : methods) {
            java.lang.invoke.MethodType mt = java.lang.invoke.MethodType.methodType(m.getReturnType(), m.getParameterTypes());
            System.out.println(m.getName() + " : " + mt.toMethodDescriptorString());
        }
    }
}
```

It prints out the following:

```
Class : Test
Number of methods : 2
main : ([Ljava/lang/String;)V
foo : (I)Ljava/lang/String;
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I don't find a "clean" solution.

Finally, I decided to create a dummy class with same methods but declared as native.
Then I use javah to create the header file and I take the signature from that header file.

I know that it does not look nice... but I don't find a better option (except creating it "manually" based on the Method properties).

Comment: I'm not looking for the C++ method signature, and anyway that's even more roundabout than using `javap -s`. What I want is to be able to get the JNI method signature string programmatically *from inside a running program*. I'll update my question to clarify.

Comment: Also, to clarify further, by "JNI method signature" I mean the signature used to call a Java method from JNI, not the signature used to implement a native method to make it Java-callable.

Comment: I understood that you were looking for this:

Comment: I understood that you were looking for this: `(II)Z`. This is the signature for a method that receives two integer as parameter and returns a boolean. I did not find the way to get that signature at runtime except creating my own Method parser. But javah utility creates a C header file which includes those signatures for the `native` methods declared on it.

Comment: javah generates the following documentation for every method: `/*
 * Class:     com_foo_mypackge
 * Method:    myJniMehod
 * Signature: (II)Z
 */`

Comment: Yes, but that's still not useful to me. I need to get it on-the-fly from any arbitrary Java class.